# How to Calculate Volume of user in JMETER Calculation

Tags: jmeter

Can any one please guide me the below Queries,

- This is my Project Requirements

  1. The test must support 2000 concurrent users per hour - this i can do from JMETER.
  2. The test must support 1 million registered users (this 1m registered users for all types of users in Web Application) - How can i Calculate to One Million Registered user from my Result.

From 2000 concurrent users Result how can i provide the Report for 1 m registered Users??

Kindly support me on this.

Answer (score 0):

1. The short & generic answer: sure you can.
   Although the longer, detailed one would very much depend on the load these 2000 users per hour would produce, so could you please clarify on that?
   E.g. if that simply translates into number of requests (1 user makes  request) - this load (2000 rph=~0.5 rps) is next to nothing for JMeter.
2. Have your million users recorded somewhere - in a file or database. Then access it from JMeter (CSV config, JDBC preprocessor, custom piece of code in BeanShell/JSR223 preprocessor) and use.

Not sure what you meant there by "Calculate to One Million Registered user from my Result" - could you please clarify somehow what you want here?

And the next sentence about "report" as well.

Comment: 1. I have to provide Results for 2000 concurrent users at peak hours

Comment: 1. I have to provide Results for 2000 concurrent users at peak hours               2. I am doing in UAT environment, there is not such amount of records available in DB. They will give only 10 Registered users. BY using 10 users by increasing loop count can I achieve 1 million users.??